# Entity Framework Issue When running Stored Procedures

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have an issue with stored procedures and Entity Framework.

Let me explain what is happening... and what I have tried thus far.

I have a stored procedure, which does not do an awful lot

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT(EmailAddress)) AcceptedQuotes, 
    CONVERT (DATE,QuoteDate) QuoteDate
FROM
    Quote Q
JOIN 
    Person P on Q.PersonPk = P.Pk
JOIN 
    Product Pr on Q.ProductPk = Pr.Pk
JOIN 
    Accepted A on Q.Pk = A.QuotePk
WHERE               
    QuoteDate between @startDate and @endDate
    AND CompanyPk = @companyPk
    AND FirstName != 'Test'
    AND FirstName != 'test'
    AND FirstName != 'EOH'
```

I want to execute this, and it works fine in SSMS and does not even take 1 second.

Now, I import this in to Entity Framework, it times out and I set the command timeout to 120...

Ok so what I have tried thus far and what I have tested.

If I use `SqlCommand`, `SqlDataAdapter`, `DataTable` way, with my own connection string, it executes as expected. When I use Entity Framework connection string in this scenario, it times out.

I altered my stored procedure to include "Recompile" option and also tried the `SET ARITHABORT` way, no luck, it times out when run through the EF.

Is this a bug in EF?

I have now just about decided to rewrite this using "old school" data access.

Also note that the EF executes fine with other stored procs, from the same database.

Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated...

PS. I found this article, but no help either :(

http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html

Comment: Can you try much simpler query without any where cluase, like select TOP 1, and see if you are getting result

Comment: Could you post the code you use to execute this query? Also, try to use sql server profiler to see what is happening under the hood. Perhaps you are passing the wrong value for the parameters in the EF case?

Comment: Well, I ran the profiler, and EF is killing the DB server. **CPU 30123**, **reads 1364453** what the hell, and this was changed to not use a where clause with parameters, and only select top 10

Comment: Can you post the query you captured from sql profiler?

Comment: Hi, ok so I created a console app having the edmx file in there, works fine with the stored proc. When I reference an assemly with the edmx file in, it dies. I even referenced the console app that works, in another console application...it dies.   exec [dbo].[spPartnerContacts] @startDate='2013-05-01 00:00:00',@endDate='2015-05-07 12:58:22',@companyPk=12

Comment: Is there any other work going on in the database? I was thinking it could be a locking issue. Depending on how your code executing the query looks like the isolation level can be different.

Comment: You you post the result from running "exec sp_who2" when you call sp from your EF

Comment: Several things pop out at me.  First on all affected tables update the statistics. "update statistics tableName".  If that doesn't immediately help then you could add the "WITH RECOMPILE" to your procedure.  If that helps then its definitely a parameter sniffing issue as mentioned above.  I am guessing on keys here but if your date fields are clustered indexes then having them passed in as @parameters could cause the sniff.  Might want to pass them in as varchars and convert them to datetime in a different variable.

Answer (score 1):

This may be caused by [Parameter Sniffing](http://blogs.technet.com/b/mdegre/archive/2012/03/19/what-is-parameter-sniffing.aspx)

When a stored procedure is compiled or recompiled, the parameter values passed for that invocation are "sniffed" and used for cardinality estimation.  The net effect is that the plan is optimized as if those specific parameter values were used as literals in the query.

> 1. Using dummy variables that are not directly displayed on parameters also ensure execution plan stability without need to add recompile
>      hint, example below:
>
> create procedure dbo.SearchProducts 
>       @Keyword varchar(100) As Declare @Keyworddummy as varchar(100) Set @Keyworddummy = @Keyword select * from Products where Keyword like
>   @Keyworddummy
>
> 2. To prevent this and other similar situations, you can use the following query option:
>
> OPTIMIZE FOR RECOMPILE
>
> 3. Disable auto-update statistics during the batch

Comment: I think it might be Parameter Sniffing or outdated statistics.